# Why is my onion pickle taking super long?

Tags: cooking-time, pickles

I made an onion pickle recipe I saw on YouTube.

It was a brine of water and vinegar (1:1) and salt.
You boil it, then pour over onion. Let cool. Store in fridge.
It's very common on YouTube. They say, it gets done in overnight.

I made it and next day it wasn't done. I left it for 2 more days and still not done. I took it out of the fridge. And 2 days later and still not done!!

**Why is it not done? and how do I make it ready quicker?**

** *My "doneness" meter is the color. Onion gets fully purple and so does the water. Mine is still just the outer surface purple and the flesh is white. The water is just semi opaque. Far from what I saw in the videos.*

---

#### Edit : extra details

Here is the video [pickled onion](https://youtu.be/K4HbmPu_M_4)
Many other videos on YT under the name "pickled onion" share the exact same recipe.

And here is a picture of my current onion
[image]
[image]
And here is what it's supposed to look like
[image]

---

#### Update : results

I tried using this patch as is.
But it was sharp and had a bitter aftertaste.
So I decided to "fix" it following your recommendations.

Here is what I suspect went wrong. First thing as you guys mentioned below, my onion was pretty thick. Also, I realized that my vinegar was very stale and I still went with (1:1) ratio with water. Also, I didn't pour the brine immediately after boiling. And I just left it outside until it just cooled down to room temp.

So here is how I tried to reverse that.
I separated the onions from the brine to change a few things :

1. I cut the onions more thin
2. I increased the vinegar concentration (by adding extra amount then boiling it)
3. I added more salt
4. I poured the boiling brine immediately on the onions
5. I left it outside the fridge for more than 3 hours

I left them for overnight because it's extremely cold here.

The results :
**Color was way off than presented** (`very pale greyish purple`).
The onion slice has a uniform color now.
Isn't vibrant whatsoever. but better than before.
**Texture was amazing**. (`Crunchy as desired`).
**Taste was pretty good**. (`very tasty and vinegary`).
I don't know if that what it supposed to taste like. But I like it so much.

If I made a new patch (I know I will) I will post if the results are different. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: That's odd. My onion pickle is essentially ready in 5 hours (first 2 hours are outside, as the mixture cools down, next 3 in the fridge). Can you show a picture of your onions?

Comment: Can you share the video link or recipe? I'm not clear on the purple part and the concept of done-ness.  Refrigerator pickles are "done" when they are flavored. Also, sometimes people add beet juice to color pickled onions red.  I don't think color is an indicator in this situation.

Comment: I do quick-pickled red onions frequently, but they do not turn "fully purple".   As such, you're going to need to share a video if you want answers.

Comment: @DonThousand I didn't leave it 2 hours outside. Just let it cool down then stored in the fridge. I added a picture to the post

Comment: @moscafj They taste like regular onions with vinegar. Still solid with the "bunchy" taste. I added the details in the post. Here is a [quick link](https://youtu.be/K4HbmPu_M_4).

Comment: @FuzzyChef I added [the link](https://youtu.be/K4HbmPu_M_4) and picture to the post. Can you check them out? How purple does it supposed to be when done?

Comment: @RooTenshi I see the issue (I think). The pieces are too big. Try to slice them longer and thinner. You want broken cells on the sides of your onions.

Comment: @DonThousand Ok I will try to slice it thinner next time. For this patch, I will see if I can slice it again. I hope this won't contaminate it

Comment: A lot of this is simply that good lighting and editing techniques are being used.

Comment: @eps ye, to some degree. But then again, other people on reddit with regular phone camera had pictures way better than mine. Although as you said, not this glowing purple like in the video

Comment: @RooTenshi I wouldn't say mine turn out as radiant as in the video, but mine are pretty close, I think. Good lighting takes it a notch above.

Comment: @DonThousand , i tried to "fix" mine. It tastes good now but the color is no way close. Idk why lol but I will take it

Comment: @RooTenshi Interesting. I'm getting a color very close to the pictured image. My mix is as follows: 1/4 white vinegar, 3/8 apple cider vinegar, 3/8 water, with sugar to taste and a pinch of salt. And then add very finely julienned onions.

Comment: @DonThousand , I will see if I can get a better patch next time. Also, does sugar play in rule in the results or just for the taste? Because I didn't add any.

Comment: @RooTenshi Just for the taste, I think. Not a chef by any means, so don't take my word for it. I'll make a batch at some point and add an image.

Comment: @DonThousand , that's cool. would love to see it. thanks for your tips tho, I've been enjoying my onions since.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refrigerator "pickles" are generally "done" when the flavor and texture is to your liking. There is no reliable color indication. There is no fermentation expected.  It is not a long term preservation technique, but rather, a flavor enhancer.  You can eat refrigerator pickles after a few minutes, or keep in the refrigerator for a couple of weeks. Just keep tasting until they are what you like.

Some things to think about: the onions in your photo are sliced more thickly and irregularly than the sample video.  The thicker your slices, the longer it will take the cell structure to break down and for them to soften and take on the flavor you are looking for. If you want to replicate what you see in the video, you have to use the same onions, and slice them the same way.

Other variables to look at, are the type of onion itself, as this will, of course, impact the flavor.  Also, consider the type of vinegar you are using.   These vary in acidity and flavor.

Finally, if you intend to use them over a few days, I would certainly not stick my fingers into the storage container, as the person in the video does.  Doing this increases the likelihood that you will introduce bacteria or mold spores into your pickles, greatly diminishing your storage time.

Comment: Ye I'm sure there is no definitive time for it to be ready. But I expect it to reach the same state in a similar frame of time. The factors you mentioned are very crucial. But would it delay the "breakage" so dramatically? Mine maintained structure (solid), taste (pungent), and color (white-ish) just like regular onions. I saw many videos, posts on reddit, they all got it quick. Do you have any recommendations do help speed the current process?

Comment: It's in my answer...slice thinly, check other variables...onion, vinegar...etc.  Yes, these can have a significant impact.

Comment: I meant the current patch. Is it salvageable? Or do I just let it do its thing and try better next time? Because I don't think I should take the onion out and slice them again. I feel like it won't be sanitary tbh

Comment: If it were me, I would just use them.

Comment: That's good too. Thank you for your answer and your time

Comment: Roo: if this answer works for you, don't forget to choose it as the answer

Comment: @FuzzyChef , Ye I was waiting a little extra time to see how it would turn. Thanks for reminding me